# Search engine for biological/medical/epidemiological science literature

Tags: research-tools

I hope this question is appropriate for this exchange (I think it is too specific for meta?).

We are looking for a search engine that is capable of performing a search of all available biological/medical/epidemiological scientific literature (So more on the scope of Google than Elsevier or similar subscription services) and providing as many as possible of the following features:

- Keyword search
- Range of dates
- Boolean terms (AND NOT etc.)
- Option to download and sort
- Email alerts.

Does anyone know of a search engine or service that has these capabilities? (A paid subscription is fine).

Thank you in advance for your patience.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this exists. The portal is called "[Pubmed](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed)" and looks like this:

[image]

This portal allows you to search (have a look into the [search-Faq](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK3827/#pubmedhelp.Advanced_Search)) in various ways as well as getting email alerts, download your searches in different formats and so on. It indexes most (but not all) scientific literature for medicine, biosciences and all related topics and is probably the biggest database in this field. And its free.

Another possibility would be [Google Scholar](https://scholar.google.de/), which is focussed on scientific literature and can also be adapted to your personal needs. However, I usually prefer using Pubmed, but sometimes it is useful as well to use Google Scholar.